# Python-Can Bus, grab only the bytes?

Tags: python, filtering, protocols, can-bus

Require some help with Python-can. At the moment, my code is just receiving data with a 2 second delay so the shell doesn't flood itself.

How do i filter the information, just so I can use the bytes received to interpret the information? At the moment its giving me everything.

```
import can
import time

bus = can.interface.Bus(bustype='nican', channel='CAN0', bitrate=1000000)

recvMsg = bus.recv(timeout=None)
while(recvMsg is not None):
    print (recvMsg.)
    time.sleep(2)
else:
    print ("None")
```

Comment: I assume `print (recvMsg.)` is a typo and you meant to write `print (recvMsg)`?!

Comment: The way you have constructed your while loop, it will not receive any further CAN-frames, but simply output the same CAN-frame over and over.
You need to add another `bus.recv` call inside the loop.

Comment: had to do some digging and exactly what you guys suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the [`message` type of `python-can`](https://python-can.readthedocs.io/en/2.2.0/message.html).

**Examples:**

If you want to print the number of bytes in the data field, use

```
print(recvMsg.dlc)
```

If you want to print the first data byte, use

```
print(recvMsg.data[0])
```